Why does BigInteger.Log10 produce a different result compared to Math.Log10
As shown, BigInteger.Log10 returns approximately 2.99999, while Math.Log10 returns exactly 3 for the same numeric value (1000).
BigInteger num1 = 1000;
long num2 = 1000;
Console.WriteLine(BigInteger.Log10(num1)); //2.99999
Console.WriteLine(Math.Log10(num2)); //3


In the end this boils down to floating point math is broken. The difference between the two methods is simply because they are implemented differently.

They probably use slightly different algorithms for approximation, resulting in a slightly different result (as metioned above the fundamental reason is related to Is floating-point math broken?).

Interestingly, BigInteger.Log2(new BigInteger(1000)) / BigInteger.Log2(new BigInteger(10)) is exactly 3. :)

I doubt either function guarantees an exact answer even when the exact answer can be represented by a double floating point number.

@Sweeper BigInteger.Log2(new BigInteger(1000)) / BigInteger.Log2(new BigInteger(10)) I was surprised by this, casting may not be the only reason for different results.
